# Change managed mobile account with server 5.2

Tags: macos, password, osx-server, user-account, accounts

So I have an account on my iMac (Sierra 10.12.6) which was managed by a mac mini with mac OS Server (5.2).
Actually, it's always considered Admin, Managed, Mobile open the iMac (even if I don't synchronize any more).
The fact that it's managed by the server is now annoying, so I wanted to free it (I want to use the server just for accessing files). The profile is set to "Home folder: local only" on the server

I'm now having trouble changing password:

- If I change on the server, it doesn't change on the iMac, so I have two different passwords for the account (one locally, the other when connecting to the server)
- If I try to change on the iMac, I have this message

  The password for the account "Frederic" was not changed. Your system administrator may not allow you to change your password or there was some other problem with your password. Contact your system administrator for help.

What can I do to change my account account to be just a local account (and to be able to change his password)?

-- Edit.

On the iMac, I was disconnected from the server in "Network Account Server". If I reconnect there, I can't log in anymore: the local password and the server's password are refused. I have to disconnect the iMac from the network (it's simple, because it's connected with Ethernet) to be able to sign in with the local password...